# Send Office Open XML file in response

Tags: mime-types, openoffice.org

I'm trying to send the content of an Open Office XML file in the response but I can't get the browser to recognize the file and open it with word. It keeps opening it as it was an XML file. I've tried setting the content type to both `application/msword` and `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`, I've also tried setting the extension to `doc` and `docx`, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML stream at the client to see what MIME type is being sent?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a programming question.  It probably belongs on super-user.

Comment: What do you mean by "open Office XML file"? Is it the content.xml or a something.odt file ? Every odt file is an XML archive.

Comment: It's a .xml file. If I open it locally it opens as a word document, but when I send it in the response, it opens as an ordinary xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be confusing "Open Office" documents with MS Office "Open XML" documents.

The former is a truly open standard (OpenDocument), which can be a single XML file, but is typically a Zipped archive of xml files and binary attachments.

The latter is a similar, but different format, that has been through the standardization process (it is an official ECMA standard), but which has gotten little adoption outside of the MS Office suite. The standardization process was very political - I'll leave it to you to look it up if you are interested.

MS Word, since 2007 SP2 can open OpenDocument (Open Office) .odt files, but I don't think that it works with the single-xml format.

So, try the .odt format.
Also, be aware that Internet Explorer tends to ignore MIME Type, and uses the file extension instead. So you should set the correct MIME Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
and set the file name to something ending in ".odt"